# How to execute particular class method with dependency injection through gradle task?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, micronaut, gradle-task

Here is my code in `build.gradle`

```
task runDataFeeder(type:JavaExec){
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    main = "example.core.RunMigrator"
}
```

And my `RunMigrator` class

```
class Migrator(@Inject val seedDataService: seedDataService) {
    fun migrate() {
        seedDataService.createZone()
    }
}

class RunMigrator {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun main(args: Array<String>) {
           Migrator().migrate()
        }
    }
}
```

**Note** `seedDataService` having methods for feeding data to a database.

I am trying to run `RunMigrator` main method from Gradle task but don't know how to inject `seedDataService` through Gradle task

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should initialize the application context in order to start a DI. It works in Java:

```
import io.micronaut.context.ApplicationContext;

public class RunMigrator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try (ApplicationContext applicationContext = ApplicationContext.run()) {
            Migrator migrator = applicationContext.getBean(Migrator.class);
            migrator.migrate();
        }
    }
}
```